# How do I pass an array without a segue?

Tags: swift, delegates, segue

I have a series of VCs. There is a restaurantMenuTableVC that is embedded in a navigationVC. When the user adds an item into the shoppingCartVC that is opened modally, I need to send the array of cart items to the paymentVC which needs to be pushed (not shown modally). So what I am doing is dismissing the shopping cart and trying to push the payment screen but nothing is working. Here is what I have tried:

Method 1 (using a simple delegate): I dismiss the shopping cart and then from the restaurantMenuVC segue to the paymentVC:

```
@IBAction func didTapNext(_ sender: UIButton) {

        dismiss(animated: true)
        delegate?.payNow()
}
```

And in the delegate function in menuVC I have this:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let paymentViewController = segue.destination as? PaymentViewController {
                paymentViewController.cartItemArray = self.cartItemArray
            }
        }
```

Well all that happens is that the shopping cart modal is dismissed but paymentVC does not open.

Method 2: In the delegate function, I have this:

```
let paymentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PaymentViewController") as? PaymentViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(paymentViewController!, animated: true)
```

This works but I cannot pass the array because there is no segue.

I cannot simply segue from the shoppingCartVC to the paymentVC because it opens the paymentVC modally. I cannot push it either because then it gets pushed twice for some reason. It UX needs to close the shoppingCartVC and then transition to the paymentVC.

What do I do?

Comment: you can use `unwind segue` or `singleton pattern` to store data.

Comment: I suggest reading about the MVC architecture.  If your data model (M) is independent, you don't have to worry about passing it around to multiple VCs.  Instead the model manages the data and VCs ask for what they need.

Comment: @PhillipMills - MVC does not mean that you you shouldn’t be passing data into the destination controller. Dependency injection is a tried and true pattern used with MVC. I understand the convenience of some shared model object, but it is not best practice.

Comment: @Rob  It's not solely about convenience; it's also about isolating responsibilities and having clear, simple relationships rather than turning view controllers into data management objects.  With a factory implementation and a protocol to use for testing, shared objects can have all the flexibility they need.

Comment: Hey, I understand the problem you’re trying to solve, but I couldn’t disagree more with the prescribed solution. But this isn’t the right place to debate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to present a scene after dismissing another, use the completion handler of `dismiss`:

```
dismiss(animated: true) {
    delegate?.payNow()
}
```

BTW, if you want to pass data when manually pushing, set the value after you instantiate the view controller, but before you push it:

```
paymentViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "PaymentViewController") as! PaymentViewController
paymentViewController.property = ...
navigationController?.pushViewController(paymentViewController, animated: true)
```

When you manually call `pushViewController`, the `prepare(for:sender:)` is not called.